# org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Incompatible types for property

Tags: jquery, json, struts2, json-rpc, struts2-json-plugin

I'm receiving a `java.util.List<Object[]>` via JSON-rpc as a JavaScript array as follows.

```
[
    [1, 0.10, 1.00],
    [2, 0.20, 2.00],
    [3, 0.30, 3.00],
    [4, 0.40, 4.00],
    [5, 0.50, 5.00],
    [6, 0.60, 6.00],
    [7, 0.70, 7.00],
    [8, 0.80, 8.00],
    [9, 0.90, 9.00],
    [10, 1.00, 10.00],
    [11, 1.10, 11.00],
    [12, 1.20, 12.00],
    [13, 1.30, 13.00],
    [14, 1.40, 14.00],
    [15, 1.50, 15.00],
    [16, 1.60, 16.00],
    [17, 1.70, 17.00],
    [18, 1.80, 18.00]
]
```

I need to pass this same array back to the server (with a little modification in the last dimension).

I use the following function to send back this array.

```
var request;
var timeout;
var itemsArray=[];

function insert()
{
    if(!request)
    {
        var i=0;

        $('input[name="txtCharge[]"]').each(function()
        {
            isNaN($(this).val())||$(this).val()===''?itemsArray[i][2]='':itemsArray[i][2]=eval(eval($(this).val()).toFixed(2));
            i++;
        });

        request = $.ajax({
            dataType:"json",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'insertZoneCharges', id:'jsonrpc', params:[itemsArray]}),
            contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
            url: "AddZoneChargeList",

            success: function(response)
            {
                alert(response.result);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                timeout = request = null;
            },
            error: function(request, status, error)
            {
                if(status!=="timeout"&&status!=="abort")
                {
                    alert(status+" : "+error);
                }
            }
        });
        timeout2 = setTimeout(function() {
            if(request)
            {
                request.abort();
                alert("The request has been timed out.");
            }
        }, 300000);
    }
}
```

The structure of the array `itemsArray` after the loop is exactly the same as mentioned in the first snippet.

The method to be invoked by this jQuery function is as follows.

```
@Namespace("/admin_side")
@ResultPath("/WEB-INF/content")
@ParentPackage(value="json-default")
public final class ZoneCharge extends ActionSupport implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public ZoneCharge() {}

    //This method is invoked by the given jQuery function. 
    //It should accept the array as a parameter of type List<Object[]> but it doesn't.
    @SMDMethod
    public String insertZoneCharges(@SMDMethodParameter(name="list")List<Object[]> list)
    {
        for(Object[]o:list)
        {
            System.out.println(o[0]+" : "+o[1]+" : "+o[2]);
        }
        return "The action completed successfully.";
    }

    @Action(value = "AddZoneChargeList",
    results = {
        @Result(name = ActionSupport.SUCCESS, type = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true"})},
    interceptorRefs = {
        @InterceptorRef(value = "json", params = {"enableSMD", "true"})})
    public String insertAction() throws Exception {
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When an attempt is made to make a request, it causes the following exception to be thrown.

```
Feb 19, 2014 6:14:00 AM org.apache.struts2.json.rpc.RPCError error
SEVERE: Incompatible types for property insertZoneCharges
org.apache.struts2.json.JSONException: Incompatible types for property insertZoneCharges
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONPopulator.convertToCollection(JSONPopulator.java:254)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONPopulator.convert(JSONPopulator.java:131)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor.invoke(JSONInterceptor.java:242)
    at org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor.intercept(JSONInterceptor.java:133)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:246)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:54)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:562)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:25)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter.doFilterInternal(MultipartFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1822)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Why isn't that array is mapped to `List<Object[]>`, when the same `List<Object[]>` is correctly mapped to an array while receiving the response from the server (this is done by a separate jQuery function which is not covered in this question)?

---

**EDIT 1:**

The following line,

```
data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'insertZoneCharges', id:'jsonrpc', params:[itemsArray]})
```

in the given jQuery function corresponds to the following string.

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "insertZoneCharges",
    "id": "jsonrpc",
    "params": [
        [
            [1, 0.1, 1],
            [2, 0.2, 2],
            [3, 0.3, 3],
            [4, 0.4, 4],
            [5, 0.5, 5],
            [6, 0.6, 6],
            [7, 0.7, 7],
            [8, 0.8, 8],
            [9, 0.9, 9],
            [10, 1, 10],
            [11, 1.1, 11],
            [12, 1.2, 12],
            [13, 1.3, 13],
            [14, 1.4, 14],
            [15, 1.5, 15],
            [16, 1.6, 16],
            [17, 1.7, 17],
            [18, 1.8, 18]
        ]
    ]
}
```

This appears valid and should correctly be mapped to `java.util.List<Object[]>` without causing the exception.

---

**EDIT 2:**

This works when the generic type parameter is removed so that the list is simply `List` (and not `<List<Object[]>>`) or the parameter is made to be of type of `List<List<Object>>`. Something like,

```
@SMDMethod
public String insertZoneCharges(@SMDMethodParameter(name="list")List<List<Object>> list)
{
    for(List<Object> o:list)
    {
        System.out.println(o);
    }
    return "The action completed successfully.";
}
```

The loop displays the following output.

```
[1, 0.1, 1]
[2, 0.2, 2]
[3, 0.3, 3]
[4, 0.4, 4]
[5, 0.5, 5]
[6, 0.6, 6]
[7, 0.7, 7]
[8, 0.8, 8]
[9, 0.9, 9]
[10, 1, 10]
[11, 1.1, 11]
[12, 1.2, 12]
[13, 1.3, 13]
[14, 1.4, 14]
[15, 1.5, 15]
[16, 1.6, 16]
[17, 1.7, 17]
[18, 1.8, 18]
```

Looking at the output, the JSON array should correctly be mapped to `List<Object[]>` but it doesn't happen.

---

**EDIT 3:** (not a substantial edit).

Although the actual array is invisible in the jQuery function given, this can simply be reproduced by the following jQuery function.

```
function insert()
{
    var a=[[1, 2], [3, 4]];  //Array.

    $.ajax({
            dataType:"json",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({jsonrpc:'2.0', method:'insertZoneCharges', id:'jsonrpc', params:[a]}),
            contentType: "application/json-rpc; charset=utf-8",
            url: "AddZoneChargeList",
            success: function(response)
            {
                alert(response.result);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                //Do something.
            },
            error: function(request, status, error)
            {
                //Do something.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And the expected method parameter of the SMD method may either be `java.util.List<Object[]>` or `java.util.List<Long[]>`. In either case, it fails with the exception given.

---

Remaining one last thing. If there is a single dimensional array like (in JavaScript),

```
var a=[1, 2];
```

then this is correctly mapped to `Long[]` (and so as to `Object[]`) as an SMD method parameter.

So, now I don't see anymore where to look.

Comment: Probably the json interceptor uses the same concept as params interceptor to map objects it apply to, doesn't it?

Comment: Other types of parameters like primitive types (and/or their wrapper types), String... are correctly mapped. Therefore, IMHO, it doesn't.

Comment: Please add answer(s), if someone has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mapping parameters incorrectly the correct mapping would be

```
@SMDMethod
public String insertZoneCharges(@SMDMethodParameter(name="list")Object[] list)
```

Comment: This works but then we have to deal with comma separated values in the object array separately as in the EDIT 2 in the question. Shouldn't it be wrong to map a JavaScript array of arrays to simply an `Object[]` or a `List` without an appropriate generic type parameter instead of mapping it to a correct type like `List<Object[]>`? This should be an oversight. Shouldn't it? If you find this is an oversight, could you please report it to Struts guys?

Comment: Tiny, JavaScript is a generic type language and it doesn't have a List type, unless it's not used in your question. You have to map javascript array `[[]]` to appropriate structure in Java and it should be definitely an array, not a list. In Java you can cast `Object[]` to `Object` it is used for the outer array, however an element of array is converted to `List<Object>`. I don't know may be some result transformers like in Hibernate can be used to transform `Object[List<Object>]` to `List<Object[]>` or write your own in a for loop. So, it's up to you.

Comment: ... note that you return back a string, but you can return `Object[]` and this is the only reason to use json-rpc. Imagine you want to write a sort action on the Java side, then you just pass the data via Ajax and return back sorted. Doing the same in javascript is hard, if you have locale specific data.

Answer (score 4):

Use the source, Luke. If you look at the class throwing that exception, you'll find that it doesn't support `List<anything[]>`. The relevant lines from `org.apache.struts2.json.JSONPopulator.convertToCollection()`:

```
232               // create an object for each element
233               for (int j = 0; j < values.size(); j++) {
234                   Object listValue = values.get(j);
235   
236                   if (itemClass.equals(Object.class)) {
237                       // Object[]
238                       newCollection.add(listValue);
239                   } else if (isJSONPrimitive(itemClass)) {
240                       // primitive array
241                       newCollection.add(this.convertPrimitive(itemClass, listValue, accessor));
242                   } else if (Map.class.isAssignableFrom(itemClass)) {
243                       Object newObject = convertToMap(itemClass, itemType, listValue, accessor);
244                       newCollection.add(newObject);
245                   } else if (List.class.isAssignableFrom(itemClass)) {
246                       Object newObject = convertToCollection(itemClass, itemType, listValue, accessor);
247                       newCollection.add(newObject);
248                   } else if (listValue instanceof Map) {
249                       // array of beans
250                       Object newObject = itemClass.newInstance();
251                       this.populateObject(newObject, (Map) listValue);
252                       newCollection.add(newObject);
253                   } else
254                       throw new JSONException("Incompatible types for property " + accessor.getName());
255               }
```

This code is adding items to the list, and falls through a series of type checks before deciding how to instantiate an object from the data. The comment on line 237 is misleading; it appears to have been copied and pasted from `convertToArray`; all it does is add the current listValue to the list. Similarly the comment on line 249 about an array isn't creating one either. In fact, there's no code in here to handle an array, so it drops through to line 254 and throws the exception you see. The code appears to be missing a couple of lines, like this:

```
else if (itemClass.isArray()) {
   Object newObject = convertToArray(itemClass, itemType, listValue, method);
   newCollection.add(newObject);
```

...translating pretty directly from the code in `convert()` for handling one dimensional arrays - which, as you noticed, work. You'd have to ask the struts developers if this is an oversight or deliberate. It does look like you're stuck with collections of collections.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. In the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.2.x/docs/json-plugin.html), I don't see anything about `List<anything[]>`. Therefore, it seems deliberate. On the other hand, an obvious question arises as to how to make this plugin process such a structure, if it is not an oversight. It is quite difficult to see plugin developers themselves can make such mistakes (confusing : a `List<Object[]>` is correctly mapped to a JavaScript array (as in the question) while retrieving but the reverse is untrue - while sending the same array back to the server)

Comment: Given that struts doesn't support lists of arrays, you've got two options: patch the plugin as I indicated above, or write your API to handle List<List> instead, possibly calling an internal List<Object[]>  method by converting with list.toArray() on each element. I feel your pain, 10 years ago I went for the first option after similar trouble with apache axis.

Comment: This is plain clumsy because even doing so may cause side effects (may be it's for this reason it is not supported). It is more or less experimental and certainly, I should not do it myself as I don't have that much sharp sight to look into an API :)

Comment: I will accept the answer later, when I find a workaround (meanwhile if you have one, please don't forget to update the answer). Thank you.